# How does Keras Tokenizer choose tokens given a sentence?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, preprocessing, tokenization

I tried to find the answer to this question but I can't find anything, so I ask here: How does Keras Tokenizer choose tokens given a sentence of words ?

To be more precise with what I want to know, given this simple example:

```
#Import module
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
# define a document
doc = ['The cat sat on the mat']
# create the tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
# fit the tokenizer on the document
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(doc)

encoded_doc=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(doc)
print('word_index : ',tokenizer.word_index)
```

This method creates the vocabulary index based on word frequency and then it basically takes each word in the text and replaces it with its corresponding integer value from the `word_index` dictionary.

Therefore, this means that in the step in which tokenizer is fit on the document (*I think* in this step), *it decides that the tokens are the words of the sentence*. Why ? Is it possible to change this choice and choose as tokens the letters of the sentence ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply how the tokenizer works given the defaults that are defined, see also [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer). By default the value for the split argument is `' '`, meaning that it splits the sentences on every space character to get the tokens for that sentence. You can change this to get other multi-character tokens from a sentence. In addition, there is the `char_level` keyword which would create tokens use each character instead of multiple characters.

Answer (score 1):

Often words are used as tokens as they carrie a meaning. This meaning is translated into "machine readable" format, which happens to be a number. So one distinct word will be one distinct token (or variable if you want to say so).

[Per docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer) you can change the TF/Keras default behaviour of "choosing words" by adding the option `char_level=True`. So in your case:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(char_level=True)
```

Character level tokens are sometimes used in ["sequence-to-sequence" models](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) in which the (sequential) prediction essentially happens at the character level.

Comment: Thank you very much !